# How can I dynamically compile a DLL using C# v3.5?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, .net-assembly

I can compile a DLL at runtime from a simple code string without any issues. Opening it in IL Spy shows exactly what it should. But if I put any extension methods in the code it outputs the following error:

```
error CS1644: Feature `extension methods' cannot be used because it is not part of the C# 2.0 language specification
```

The only help I could find says I should be able to set the "CompilerVersion" to "v3.5" by providing a dictionary of options to the code provider, but it doesn't help at all.

Here's my code:

```
var options = new System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary<string, string> { { "CompilerVersion", "v3.5" } };
var codeProvider = new Microsoft.CSharp.CSharpCodeProvider(options);
var provider = System.CodeDom.Compiler.CodeDomProvider.CreateProvider("CSharp");
var parameters = new System.CodeDom.Compiler.CompilerParameters();
parameters.GenerateExecutable = false;
parameters.OutputAssembly = "AutoGen.dll";
var results = provider.CompileAssemblyFromSource(parameters, code);
Debug.Log(results.Errors.DeepToString());
```

Comment: Why not just not use the extension method in the dynamic code and call the function statically instead.

Comment: Because the idea is to generate a DLL that can contain any code the user gives it which would normally work in a Unity script. I'd rather not just ban this language feature because it's useful and I don't know what else I'd be inadvertantly banning as well. Surely this isn't an impossible problem to solve?